# pip3 throws exception

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am macOS High Sierra. I installed Python3 using homebrew (`brew install python`). Python3 seems to be installed but pip3 is not working. I get following error
[image]

Here is output when I install Python
[image]
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this resolved by adding following in my `.zshrc` file

```
alias pip3="python3 -m pip"
# check if it working by opening a new tab and try
pip3 --version
```